# Selenium: How to locate next child element

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am having trouble writing the exact location of the second div.row element based on the child element preceding it (which is the second div.trigger element in the page)

```
<div id='subscription'></div>
<div class='settings'></div>
<div class='generic'></div>
<div class='trigger'></div>
<div class='row'></div>
<div class='trigger'></div>
<div class='row'></div>
```

The reason for this is that, upon loading a page, no trigger elements initially appear. But when I click on a checkbox, one trigger appears, and so on since there are at least 3 checkboxes in the page.

Sorry for the noobness of this question, but i haven't found a solution yet and i'm hopelessly stuck. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take all div with class 'row' and than take 2-nd one

```
//div[@class='row'][2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `xpath-expression` like below which should work:

```
By.xpath("//div[@class='settings']/child::div[position()=2][attribute::class='row']");
```

(or)

```
By.xpath("//div[@class='settings']/following-sibling::chapter[position()=1]");
```